# Debug HTTP Module Init Event From ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

Is it possible to debug the init event from a http module? If I set breakpoints, they don't get triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach a debugger at runtime by adding the following before the point you want to debug

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

It will open the debug window and offer you options regarding what to do

Comment: Interesting. Can you also explain how this works? Breakpoints in events attached to the HttpApplication get hit, a breakpoint in Init not, but with this code it will.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in the point of the break point...

```
Debug.Fail("Just a Break");
```